# Rails is looking for Update when it should be Create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to make a comment form on my Collection show page. I'm a bit rusty with Rails and I'm not sure why this form isn't attempting to Create a comment and is instead returning the error

> The action 'update' could not be found for CommentsController

The comments system works in console.

Here is my form

```
<%= form_for [@commentable, @comment] do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
    <%= f.submit "Comment", class: "btn btn-large btn" %>
  <% end %>
```

My comment model

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
    belongs_to :user
end
```

My collection model

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

My comments_controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)
    if @comment.save
         flash[:success] = 'Comment posted!' 
      redirect_to @commentable
    else 
      flash[:notice] = "Error creating comment: #{@comment.errors}" 
      redirect_to @commentable
    end 
  end 

  private
    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :commentable_type, :commentable_id, :user_id)
    end
end
```

My collections_controller show action

```
def show
    @collection = Collection.find(params[:id])
    @commentable = @collection
    @comments = @commentable.comments
    @comment = Comment.new if user_signed_in?
end
```

Comment: You misspelled @commentable in your form :)

Comment: Thank you. Good spot. Unfortunately doesn't fix everything but it would certainly break it if it was working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using @commentable in your form or controller, which may be causing your problem:

```
<%= form_for [@commentable, @comment] do |f| %>
```

And your controller action should look like this:

```
def create
  @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)
```

Update: Then to load commentable based on resource:

```
before_filter: load_commentable

def load_commentable
  resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1, 2]
  @commentable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
end
```

Method courtesy Ryan Bates: http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association-revised

Comment: That makes sense. I can see I should be using @commentable. Thanks. I'm still getting the same error though. I don't see why it is trying to update rather than create.

Comment: This is also currently creating a blank comment every time the Show page loads. I'm so rusty. Many apologies.

Comment: YESS! I was missing the load_commentable bit. Not paying close enough attention to Ryan Bates is always a surefire path to failure. Thanks for being so eagle eyed. Pretty much working now, just have to pass in the user_id and it's perfect. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show the controller action that renders that forms? I think the problem is that `@comment` is already persisted/created so it tries to update it.

UPDATE:

I just noticed your show action. Yes the problem is that `@comment` is already persisted. Just change it to:

`@comment = Comment.new if user_signed_in?`

Comment: That seems to get past that problem but now I've got "undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass" for my Create action.

Comment: `current_user` is nil. Can you show the definition of `current_user` ?

Comment: I've taken that out and edited it following the other answer. No reference to current_user now. I guess the problem now is I'm not passing the @commentable.

Comment: Do i need a hidden field for that or am I passing it because the form_for contains @commentable and @comment? Oof

Comment: if you are using `[@commentable, @comment]` then you need to  load the `@commentable` variable like: `@commentable = Collection.find(params[:commentable_id])`

Comment: The reason I'm using @commentable is so it can be something other than a Collection. It could also be a Post or a User for instance. So I need to pass to the create action the fact that the Commentable is in this case a comment. This is why I have a commentable_type and commendable_id field in my Comment model. I need them in the form as hidden fields right? Really sorry to be so useless today.